# Add textbox value to datagrid row in wpf

Tags: wpf, mvvm, datagrid, textbox

I'm developing a WPF application with MVVM pattern.

I'm populating data to gridview and on selection, I populate to textbox,combobox to edit the contents. then Save the data.

Now I want to add new data to the grid view.
User input to textbox,combo box should be add to grid view and the i need to save it to data base.

my XMAL is as follows:

```
<Grid Height="444" Width="486">
    <Label Content="Script" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="13,36,0,0" Name="lblScript" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
    <TextBox Height="142" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="75,38,0,0" Name="txtScript" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="380"  Text="{Binding Script_Text}"/>
    <Button Content="Add"  Command="{Binding SaveData}"  Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="284,409,0,0" Name="btnSave" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" />
    <Button Content="Reset"  Command="{Binding ClearData}" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="380,409,0,0" Name="btnReset" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" />

    <DataGrid  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Param}" HeadersVisibility="Column" SelectionMode="Single" 
               AlternatingRowBackground="Gainsboro" Background="White" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
               ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource itemstyle}" CanUserAddRows="True" GridLinesVisibility="None" 
               Height="150" HorizontalAlignment="Left" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left"  IsEnabled="True" 
               IsReadOnly="True"   Margin="75,200,0,0" Name="dgMain" RowHeight="23" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
               VerticalContentAlignment="Center"  Width="380" >
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDoubleClick">
                <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding EditData}"/>
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Name}" Header="Parameter" Width="140" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Type}" Header="Type" Width="100" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Value}" Header="Value" Width="120" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>

    </DataGrid>
    <Label Content="Name" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="75,186,0,0" Name="lblName" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
    <TextBox Height="23" Text="{Binding SelectedItem.Name, ElementName=dgMain}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="75,213,0,0" Name="txtName" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="110" />
    <Label Content="Type" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="191,186,0,0" Name="lblType" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
    <ComboBox Height="23" Text="{Binding SelectedItem.Type, ElementName=dgMain}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="191,213,0,0" Name="cboType" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="110" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
        <ComboBoxItem Content="integer" />
        <ComboBoxItem Content="double" />
        <ComboBoxItem Content="string" />
    </ComboBox>
    <Label Content="Value" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="307,186,0,0" Name="lblValue" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
    <TextBox Height="23" Text="{Binding SelectedItem.Value, ElementName=dgMain}"   HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="307,213,0,0" Name="textBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="110" />

    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="428,15,0,0" Height="32">
            <ToggleButton  x:Name="Add" Focusable="False" Command ="{Binding AddNew}" Style="{StaticResource SMToggle}" >
                <Image Source="/Image/Add.png"  Width="16" Height="16" />
            </ToggleButton>
    </TextBlock>
</Grid>
```

Please help me.
SN

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are correctly using MVVM, that your `Param` property is a collection and that your `SelectedItem` property is of the same type as the items in the collection, you should just be able to do this in the `SaveData` command in your view model:

```
Param.Add(SelectedItem);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MVVM, then instead of binding TextBox/ComboBox directly to the datagrid, bind them to a property of type Parameter (e.g. `public Parameter DisplayedParameter {get; set; }`)  in your ViewModel. Then support two modes for your TextBox/ComboBox - Add and Edit.

When in Add Mode, simply set the DisplayedParameter to a new instance of Parameter. On click of Save button, save the parameter to the backend and refresh the value of Param Property (which I assume is the List/ObservableCollection of Parameter). Alternatively, add the parameter to the Param list, and then save the parameter to the backend.

When in Edit Mode, simply set the DisplayedParameter to the value of SelectedItem (you will need a viewmodel property for SelectedItem also). On click of Save, you can save the edited parameter in backend and refresh the Param.

Notice that, by default, you remain in Add mode; and switch to edit mode only when user requests so (e.g. selecting an item in datagrid, or maybe clicking an edit button in the row of datagrid). Once you are done with the edit (e.g. user saves or cancels), you go back to your default mode.